# Discontinuity of Monotone function

Tags: real-analysis

This question was asked in a masters exam for which I am preparing and I couldn't solve it.

> Let F: $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be a monotone function. Then which 1 is true:

(i) F has no discontinuity.

(ii)F has only finitely many discontinuity.

(iii) F can have atmost countable many discontinuity.

(iv) F have uncountably many discontinuity.

I am sorry but I won't be able to provide any attempt for it as I am clueless on which result should I use to solve this question.

Background : I have studied real analysis from Tom M apostol's Mathematical analysis.

Kindly shed some light on it.

Comment: Each of (i), (ii) is true for some monotone functions $F$; each of (i), (ii) is false for some monotone functions $F$; (iii) is true for all monotone functions $F$ (moreover, this is also true for some monotone functions $F$ if "at most countable" is replaced by "countably infinitely"); (iv) is false for all monotone functions $F.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F$ can have at most countable many discontinuity.

Without loss of generality let $F$ be increasing. For every $x,F(x^{-}),F(x^{+})$ exists except at most in the extreme of the interval where we consider only a left or right neighborhood.

Let $\omega(x) := F(x^{+}) - F(x^{-})$, otherwise said $\omega(x)$ is the "jump" in $x$.

So $F$ is discontinuos if and only if, being monotonic increasing, $w(x) > 0$.

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \hspace{0.2cm} S_{n}:=\{x : \omega(x) \geq \frac{1}{n}\}$$

If $p_{1}\cdots p_{k}$ are distinct points of $S_{n}$ then the sum of the jumps in those points is at most $F(b)-F(a)$.

From which we deduce $\frac{k}{n} \leq F(b)-F(a) \hspace{0.2cm} i.e \hspace{0.1cm} k \leq n(F(b)-F(a))$.

So we proved that for every fixed $n$,$S_{n}$ is finite.
Consequently $\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} S_{n} = Disc(f)$ is countable union of finite set, hence countable, which concludes our proof.